# Can Backbone emulateJSON emulateHTTP be set locally?

Tags: backbone.js

Part of my backbone app was written before our application server can support JSON and RESTful API.  Is there a way to set emulateJSON & emulateHTTP locally per model?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass them in to the options into the call to [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch), [save](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) or [destroy](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy) functions.

```
var model = new Backbone.Model();
model.fetch({emulateHTTP: true});
```

Alternately if you want the whole model to use it you could overwrite the `sync` function of the model to pass it through automatically:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // ...
    sync: function(method, model, options){
        var alteredOptions = _.extend({emulateJSON: true}, options);
        return Backbone.Model.prototype.sync.call(this, method, model, alteredOptions);
    }
    // ...
});
```

If you have a look at the annotated source for [Backbone.sync](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-144) you will see that they are defaults if you don't pass them in yourself.